# Concatenate 2 or more arrays into unique combinations in new list

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I am working on a problem where I have can have 2 or more arrays of string values.

Starting with the first array, I need to take each value and concatenate the first value of the next array and the first from the third and so on until all possible combinations have been combined.

Example:

```
Array1 {'A', 'B'}
Array2 {'C', 'D', 'E'}
Array3 {'F', 'G', 'H'}
```

Output would be

```
Row 1 = A, C, F
Row 2 = A, C, G
Row 3 = A, C, H
Row 4 = A, D, F
Row 5 = A, D, G
Row 6 = A, D, H
```

and so on until all combinations are completed.  In this case it would be 18 combinations.

I have used string concatenation before to combine the values, but never in a process like this where the number of arrays could change and the number of items within to produce this type of output.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) is the answer

```
List<string[]> lists = new List<string[]>()
{
    new[]{"A", "B"},
    new[]{"C", "D", "E"},
    new[]{"F", "G", "H"}
};

var cp = lists.CartesianProduct();

foreach(var line in cp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",line));
}
```

---

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    //http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        // base case: 
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        foreach (var sequence in sequences)
        {
            var s = sequence; // don't close over the loop variable 
            // recursive case: use SelectMany to build the new product out of the old one 
            result =
                from seq in result
                from item in s
                select seq.Concat(new[] { item });
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested for loops would work for this:

```
for (int i=0;i<=Array1.Length;i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j<=Array2.Length; j++)
  {
    for (int k=0;k<=Array3.Length; k++)
      //output however Array1[i] + ", " + Array2[j] + ", " + Array3[k];
  }
}
```

Comment: And what about if there is another array?

Comment: This method would work for 3 arrays, but it would need to keep nesting for n-arrays. This would also largely increase the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) algorithm to list all the combinations:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CartesianProduct
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] array1 = new char[] { 'A', 'B' };
            char[] array2 = new char[] { 'C', 'D', 'E' };
            char[] array3 = new char[] { 'F', 'G', 'H' };

            int iterations = array1.Length * array2.Length * array3.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", array1[i % array1.Length], array2[i % array2.Length], array3[i % array3.Length]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total iterations: " + iterations.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```