# F# Array Of String: concatenating values

Tags: f#

I have an array like this:

```
let items = ["A";"B";"C";"D"]
```

I want to transform it into an array like this:

```
let result = ["AB";"AC";"AD";"BC";"BD";"CD"]
```

I can't find anything in the language spec that does this - though I might be searching incorrectly.  I thought of Seq.Fold like this:

```
let result = items |> Seq.fold(fun acc x -> acc+x) ""
```

but I am getting `"ABCD"`

Does anyone know how to do this?  Will a modified [CartesianProduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022754/concatenate-2-or-more-arrays-into-unique-combinations-in-new-list) work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
items
|> List.map (fun x -> items |> List.map (fun y -> (x, y)))
|> List.concat
|> List.filter (fun (x, y) -> x < y)
|> List.map (fun (x, y) -> x + y)
|> List.sort
```

I don't know if it's efficient for large lists, but it does produce this output:

```
["AB"; "AC"; "AD"; "BC"; "BD"; "CD"]
```

**Breakdown**

The first step produces a list of list of tuples, by mapping `items` twice:

```
[[("A", "A"); ("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D")];
 [("B", "A"); ("B", "B"); ("B", "C"); ("B", "D")];
 [("C", "A"); ("C", "B"); ("C", "C"); ("C", "D")];
 [("D", "A"); ("D", "B"); ("D", "C"); ("D", "D")]]
```

Second, `List.concat` turns the list of list into a single list:

```
[("A", "A"); ("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("B", "A"); ("B", "B");
 ("B", "C"); ("B", "D"); ("C", "A"); ("C", "B"); ("C", "C"); ("C", "D");
 ("D", "A"); ("D", "B"); ("D", "C"); ("D", "D")]
```

Third, `List.filter` removes the tuples where the first element is equal to or larger than the second element:

```
[("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("B", "C"); ("B", "D"); ("C", "D")]
```

Fourth, `List.map` produces a list of concatenated strings:

```
["AB"; "AC"; "AD"; "BC"; "BD"; "CD"]
```

Finally, `List.sort` sorts the list, although in this case it's not necessary, as the list already has the correct order.

You might also consider using `Seq.distinct` to remove duplicates, if there are any.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I guess there is nothing out of the box in the F# spec that does this.  Drat!  I prefer Mark's syntax to Jack's because I really try and avoid using "if...else" when I write F#.  Both will work - hope this helps someone else...

Comment: @JamieDixon One thing to consider -- if your lists or arrays are relatively large, avoiding the "if ... else" syntax is going to cost you a lot of performance. Mark's solution produces the result you want, but it also has a significant amount of overhead (both CPU and memory/GC) since it creates a new list between each step. The difference won't be noticeable for small lists, but it will be for larger lists.

Comment: Well, I *did* say that "I don't know if it's efficient for large lists", but the part about creating a new list every time can be easily addressed. You can replace all the `List` functions with `Seq` functions in the above code, and it will still work... e.g. replace `List.map` with `Seq.map`, `List.concat` with `Seq.concat`, etc. I just used functions from the `List` module because it's easier to look at results in F# Interactive, and because the OP asked for a list.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there are lists, not arrays -- lists use the `[...]` syntax, arrays use the `[|...|]` syntax.

That said, here's a simple implementation:

```
let listProduct (items : string list) =
    items
    |> List.collect (fun x ->
        items
        |> List.choose (fun y ->
            if x < y then Some (x + y)
            else None))
```

If you put it into F# interactive:

```
> let items = ["A"; "B"; "C"; "D"];;

val items : string list = ["A"; "B"; "C"; "D"]

> items |> listProduct |> Seq.toList;;
val it : string list = ["AB"; "AC"; "AD"; "BC"; "BD"; "CD"]
```

Comment: This only works if your inputs are sorted right? If the user has ["d"; "b"; "a"] then it won't work

Comment: @devshorts That's correct. The question doesn't state the input would be sorted, but that seems to be the case given the example input and output data. If not, you'd need to sort the input (e.g., with `List.sort`) first.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function to create a list of all head/tail pairs in a list:

```
let rec dec = function
| [] -> []
| (x::xs) -> (x, xs) :: dec xs
```

or a tail-recursive version:

```
let dec l =
    let rec aux acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | (x::xs) -> aux ((x, xs)::acc) xs

    aux [] l |> List.rev
```

you can then use this function to create your list:

```
let strs (l: string list) = l |> dec |> List.collect (fun (h, t) -> List.map ((+)h) t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
let rec loop = function 
    [] -> []
  | x :: xs -> List.map ((^) x) xs @ loop xs
```

This has the advantage of not building every pair of elements from the list only to discard half. (I'll leave getting rid of the append as an exercise :-)

For me, it is a bit easier to tell what's going on here compared some of the other proposed solutions. For this kind of problem, where to process an element x you need also access to the rest of the list xs, standard combinators won't always make solutions clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
let items = ["A";"B";"C";"D"]
let rec produce (l: string list) =
    match l with
    // if current list is empty or contains one element - return empty list
    | [] | [_] -> [] 
    // if current list is not empty - match x to head and xs to tail
    | x::xs -> 
        [
            // (1) 
            // iterate over the tail, return string concatenation of head and every item in tail 
            for c in xs -> x + c 
            // apply produce to tail, concat return values
            yield! produce xs
        ]
```

1st iteration: l = [A, B, C, D] - is not empty, in second match case we'll have x = A, xs = [B, C, D]. 'for' part of the list expression will yield [AB, AC, AD] and result of applying `produce` to xs.

2nd iteration:l = [B, C, D] is not empty so second match case we'll have x = B, xs = [C, D]. 'for' part of the list expression will yield [BC, BD] and result of applying `produce` to xs.

3rd iteration:l = [C, D] is not empty in second match case we'll have x = C, xs = [D]. 'for' part of the list expression will yield [CD] and result of applying `produce` to xs.

4th iteration:l = [D] contains one element -> return empty list.

Final result will be concatenation of [AB, AC, AD] ++ [BC, BD] ++ [CD]

Answer (score 1):

This is an apt motivating example for implementing a List monad in F#. Using F# computation expressions, we get:

```
type ListMonadBuilder() = 
    member b.Bind(xs, f) = List.collect f xs
    member b.Delay(f)    = fun () -> f()
    member b.Let(x, f)   = f x
    member b.Return(x)   = [x]
    member b.Zero()      = []

let listM = new ListMonadBuilder()
```

Now, to solve the original problem we simply use our List monad.

```
let run = listM {
    let! x = ['A' .. 'D']
    let! y = List.tail [ x  .. 'D']
    return string x + string y
}
```

`run();;` in F# Interactive will return the desired result.

For another example of using the List monad, we can get the Pythagorean triples `<= n`.

```
let pythagoreanTriples n = listM {
    let! c = [1 .. n]
    let! b = [1 .. c]
    let! a = [1 .. b]
    if a*a + b*b = c*c then return (a, b, c)
}
```

Running `pythagoreanTriples 10 ();;` in F# interactive returns:

```
val it : (int * int * int) list = [(3, 4, 5); (6, 8, 10)]
```

Comment: You can use List.collect instead of concatMap